# Why is the nullspace 1 in this matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

I have the following matrix: \begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&1\\1&2&3\end{bmatrix}
I'm tasked with finding the nullspace and the range of it.
I can clearly see that the rank is 2.
The nullspace is 1 because of some theorem where the nullspace+rank=number of rows or columns.

What I don't understand is why the nullspace is 1 and not 2 in this matrix.

If I rewrite it I get: 
1x=-2y-3z=-2s-3t

y=s

z=t

s[-2,1,0]

t[-3,0,1]

Videos such as these: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpcCNOe-oyE imply this is how you find the nullspace.

Comment: It's not clear to me how you've computed the solutions, but $[-3,0,1]$ is not in the nullspace - consider the second row of the given matrix.

Comment: The word null**space** refers to the *space* itself, not the dimension of the space.  You mean to say the *nullity* of the matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $A$ is your matrix, then its null space is the set of those vectors $(x,y,z)$ such that $A.(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)$. But\begin{align}A.(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)&\iff\left\{\begin{array}{l}0=0\\z=0\\x+2y+3z=0\end{array}\right.\\&\iff\left\{\begin{array}{l}x=-2y\\z=0.\end{array}\right.\end{align}So, the null space is $\{(-2y,y,0)\mid y\in\mathbb R\}$, whose dimension is $1$.

Comment: Thank you that was helpful.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.